# SP 2010: How to search for a Content Type in a KeywordQuery?

Tags: keywordquery

I want to search all of my Sites for a special Content Type with a Keyword Query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a custom Managed Property in your Search Service Application that maps to the crawled property ows_ContentType.

Refer [here](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html) and [here](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/01/refining-on-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/) for some help with that.  (You can ignore the more advanced instructions on how to then create a refinement filter based on that, unless you want a refinement filter...)  Be sure to run a full crawl after setting up the mapping.

Then you can use a property restriction keyword query for that managed property.  For instance, if you named your managed property "ContentTypeName", you could use the property restriction keyword query:

```
ContentTypeName:"my special content type"
```